# Deactivate Slack account without access to associated email address

Tags: slack

If someone has an old Slack account with an email address they no longer have access to, how can they deactivate that account?

Comment: To clarify: Are you sure you want to "deactivate" the account, or rather re-activate?

Answer (score 2):

Users with the role `owner` in a Slack workspace can deactivate any account of another user. No matter if the email address still exists or not.